# Can you use a subquery in LPAD?

Tags: oracle11g

I have a list of 9 digit IDs in a table I called "numbers", with one column called "ID".  I want to use those in a subquery to look for specific rows in a table called artransaction.  The problem is that in the transactionid column in artransaction, it has a zero in front of the 9 digit ID.

So if I do:

```
select * from artransaction
where transactionid in lpad((select id from numbers where rownum=1),10,'0');
```

It comes back with a result.  But if I do:

```
select * from artransaction
where transactionid in lpad((select id from numbers),10,'0');
```

It says "single-row subquery returns more than one row"

Is it possible to put in a subquery in LPAD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rewrite that query. Here's an example based on Scott's EMP table - I want to select rows that contain COMM which *looks like* the ones stored in the NUMBERS table.

```
SQL> select ename, comm from emp order by ename;

ENAME            COMM
---------- ----------
ALLEN             300
BLAKE
CLARK
FORD
JAMES
JONES
KING
MARTIN           1400
MILLER
SMITH
TURNER              0
WARD              500

12 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Sample NUMBERS table:

```
SQL> create table numbers (comm number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into numbers values (14);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into numbers values (50);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into numbers values (3);

1 row created.

SQL> select * From numbers;

      COMM
----------
        14
        50
         3

SQL>
```

Testing:

```
SQL> -- This one will work because of the ROWNUM = 1 condition, which returns a single value
SQL> select * from emp
  2  where comm in rpad((select comm from numbers where rownum = 1), 4, '0');

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE          SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN        7698 28.09.1981       1250       1400         30

SQL> -- This will result in error because NUMBERS contain several values
SQL> select * from emp
  2  where comm in rpad((select comm from numbers), 4, '0');
where comm in rpad((select comm from numbers), 4, '0')
                    *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row


SQL> -- So - rewrite it
SQL> select * from emp
  2  where comm in (select rpad(comm, 3, '0') from numbers);

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE          SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7521 WARD       SALESMAN        7698 22.02.1981       1250        500         30
      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        7698 20.02.1981       1600        300         30

SQL>
```

Or, applied to your query:

```
select * from artransaction
where transactionid in (select lpad(id, 10, '0') from numbers);
```

Comment: Thanks that works perfectly, looks like the lpad needs to be used inside the subquery, not around it.

Comment: Exactly; you got it.